# Linux command to filter records from a file that does not start with number

Tags: linux, shell

I have a file in linux .

It has many records

1st record is header and the some records with data records  and the last record is footer record

records.txt

```
1MJ M062021
JKYCNY  MJ   0621 0000000002 00000001000 00000000100
MYFCNT  MJ   0621 0000000003 00000003000 00000000100
JKYCNY  MJ   0621 0000000004 00000010000 00000000100
JKYCNY  MJ   0621 0000000005 00000025000 00000000100
aYFCNT  MJ   0621 0000000006 00000001000 00000000100
JKYCNY  MJ   0621 0000000007 00000003000 00000000100
MYFCNT  MJ   0621 0000000008 00000010000 00000000100
JKYCNY  MJ   0621 0000000009 00000005000 00000000100
JKYCNY  MJ   0621 0000000010 00000010000 0000000010
JKYCNY  MJ   0621 0000043199 00000000100 00000000100
JKYCNY  MJ   0621 0000043200 00000000100 00000000100
9000000000042723
```

I want only the data records , I want to skip the header record and tailer record , some times in this file there wont be header record .

I want to fetch only the data records and store that result as a file

Below command gives me only the header and footer record alone ,

```
 grep "^[1,9]" records.txt
```

But what is the command to skip these two records alone , I tried the below command , but it did not help

```
 grep "!^[1,9]" records.txt
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`[1,9]` means "one of the characters <kbd>1</kbd>, <kbd>,</kbd> or <kbd>9</kbd>. That's probably not what you meant. Maybe you meant `[19]` (one or nine) or maybe you meant `[0-9]` (any digit). I'm assuming that you meant "any digit" because that's what you said in the title. If you meant something else, I hope that it will be obvious how to fix it.

To invert the set of characters which could match, put a `^` right after the `[`. So `[^0-9]` means "anything other than a digit".

The `^` at the beginning of the pattern means "only match at the beginning of a line". But it only means that at the beginning of the pattern.

So `^[^0-9]` matches a line which starts with something other than a digit.

Neither of those patterns will match an empty line, since both of them match exactly one character.

Normally, grep searches for the pattern anywhere in a line, and prints the line if it finds the pattern. But if you put a `^` at the beginning of the pattern, it only checks the beginning of the line. You can also put a `$` at the end of the pattern to mean "only match at the end of the line". If you use both `^` at the beginning and `$` at the end, you are asking grep to print lines which precisely match the pattern. You don't need to know that for this question, but it will come in handy some day.

Answer (score 2):

Try `grep "^[^19]" records.txt`

Answer (score 2):

Something like

```
grep -v '^[0-9]'
```

This writes to stdout all lines where the first character is not a digit.

Answer (score 2):

All the answers seems good. Just wanna add another option. `sed`

```
sed -En '/^([[:alpha:]]+\s+)+/p' records.txt
```

To write in-place and create a backup:

```
sed -Eni.bak '/^([[:alpha:]]+\s+)+/p' records.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

You are talking about removing a header and a footer. For this (just removing the footer), I've made this small oneliner:

```
head -n $(($(wc -l test.txt | awk '{print $1}') - 1)) test.txt
```

Obviously, this is far too complicated. Feel free to simplify it.

This is what it means:

```
wc -l test.txt     : count the amount of lines (and in the result,
                      show also the filename)
| awk '{print $1}' : only show the amount of lines, not the filename
$((... - 1))       : subtract 1
head -n ...        : show the first ... entries of the file. As that amount
                     equals the number of lines minus one, it shows
                     everything but the footer.
```